# Simple way to populate a collection with ViewModel objects with domain object properties to pass to index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC.NET (and development generally really) and I'm really starting to see the light of the benefit of ViewModels.

So, I'm currently refactoring one of my index methods to send a collection of ViewModel objects to the view. However, I'm not quite sure of the best way to achieve this.

Basically, my domain model is a `UseCase` and my ViewModel is `UserGoalsStepViewModel`. I know that in my `UserGoalIndex` action I'll need a collection to contain my ViewModel objects, each of these having had it's properties set by each `UseCase` that exists, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Help much appreciated.

*Note: I know I could be using `AutoMapper` and probably a lot of other techniques to make life easier, but as I'm new to this (and time pressured!) I'm just looking for the simplest approach possible.*

**UseCase Model**

```
public enum Level
{
    Summary, UserGoal, SubGoal,
}
public class UseCase
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    public virtual int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual Project project { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int ActorID { get; set; }  
    [DisplayName("Actor")]
    public virtual Actor actor { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Level? Level { get; set; }
    public virtual string Precondition { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Minimal Guarantee")]
    public virtual string MinimalGuarantee { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Success Guarantee")]
    public virtual string SuccessGuarantee { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Extension> Extensions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Query> Queries { get; set; }

}
```

**UserGoalViewModel** *(subset of UseCase properties)*

```
public class UserGoalsStepViewModel
    {
        public enum GoalLevel
        {
            Summary, UserGoal, SubGoal,
        }

            public int ProjectId { get; set; }
            //ActorId removed as SelectedActorId is what binds to model 
            //public int ActorId { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Actor Title")]    
            public SelectList ActorList { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Actor Title")]
            public string ActorTitle { get; set; }
            public int SelectedActorId { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Goal Title")]
            public string GoalTitle { get; set; }
            public GoalLevel Level { get; set; }

            public UserGoalsStepViewModel ()
            {

            }


    }
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Do you want to initialize a new `UserGoalsStepViewModel` and map the properties of an exiting `UseCase` to it? What is `public string ActorTitle { get; set; }` in your view model (you are using a `SelectList` for `ActorList` so what is the purpose of the property - you would bind to `SelectedActorId`). Ditto for `GoalTitle`. And `[DisplayName("Actor Title")]` on a `SelectList` property does not make sense. And what is the difference between `ActorId` and `SelectedActorId`?

Comment: Used for my Index view - I needed to take my `UseCases` and populate a ViewModel object for each of them. I did refactor my ViewModel - `ActorId` was redundant so was removed. Not sure why there is an issue with `GoalTitle` though - this binds to `Title` in my model. Also, I think it is valid to use `[DisplayName("Actor Title")]` for a `SelectList` as this is the label I wanted to show next to my list of `Actors` on my Edit View (I realise now I should have probably used a different ViewModel for my Edit and my Index). I might be missing some stuff though and appreciate the advice :-)

Comment: It's pointless to use `[DisplayName("Actor Title")]` for a `SelectList` property because the `SelectList` is used for generating the list of options - your not binding to it - your binding to `SelectedActorId` so that property should have the attribute (a `<label>` is associated with the property your binding to). You can easily use a LINQ `.Select(i => new UserGoalsStepViewModel {...})` to map you properties.